# Drupal6: Content Access Permissions can't be rebuilt

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-6, content-type

I created a new content type, so it wants me to rebuild content permissions. I clicked the link to do so. It progressed through but seemed to get hung up towards the end. It stayed in the same position for 20 minutes, so hit refresh. I got the following error message:

`The content access permissions have not been properly rebuilt.`

What is wrong here?

**UPDATE:** The problem appears to be with the `Nodeaccess` module. When I disable it, this problem goes away. When I re-enable it, the problem returns. I'm not sure what to do about it, as that module is essential to the functionality of my site.

**UPDATE 2**: I installed `Content Access` instead of `Nodeaccess`, but the problem persists. Perhaps it's some underlying issue with my site?

Comment: what modules, in what versions, do you have installed and enabled?

Comment: looks like `Nodeaccess` was the problem, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

A few people on drupal.org have posted about changing database from mysqli to mysql in settings.php
Not sure if that is the right way, but here are the pointers https://drupal.org/node/363316